# How to set a unique message for a rule on multiple inputs in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, input, validation, validationrules

My view contains a form with 3 similar inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="email1" />
<input type="text" name="email2" />
<input type="text" name="email3" />
```

I added a callback to control that each textbox does not get the current session email.

```
public function check_session_email($email){
    if($this->session){
        if ($this->session->userdata('email') != $email){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_session_email', 'You can't include your own email address.');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

If I used the current session email, the error message displays twice (same thing with three).

[image]

Of course, that sounds logical ...but not very user-friendly. So my question is : how to include only one error message for a rule?

Comment: If you can get CI to put the messages in an array, you could use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to validate this outside of the Form Validation Library.

Controller method:

```
// general validation rules

if( $this->input->post('email1') == $this->session->userdata('email') || $this->input->post('email2') == $this->session->userdata('email') || $this->input->post('email3') == $this->session->userdata('email') )
{
    $data['own_mail_error'] = true;
}

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE || isset($data['own_mail_error']))
{
  $this->load->view('myform', $data);
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('formsuccess');
}
```

And your view:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php if(isset($own_mail_error)): ?>
<p>You can't include your own email address.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I replaced the first line by `if(in_array($this->session->userdata('email'), $this->input->post()))` to get something shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function check_session_email($email)
    {
        if($this->session)
        {
            if ($this->session->userdata('email') != $email)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            if($this->form_validation->_field_data['email1']['error']=='' && $this->form_validation->_field_data['email2']['error']=='' && $this->form_validation->_field_data['email3']['error']=='')
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('check_session_email', 'You can\'t include your own email address.');
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```